# Transparency on image and text

Tags: android, textview, imageview, styles

I want display my items image and title this format in android I have a preview beautiful sample image for this format please see my sample image [image: My sample image]

I'm using this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.testforme.android.sample.ItemListActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="#FFF" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/article_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/item_img"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#7000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="#000"
            android:shadowDx="3"
            android:shadowDy="3"
            android:shadowRadius="6"
            android:text="Styling Android"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="A guide to applying styles and themes to Android apps"
            android:textColor="#CCC"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

but my result this is:
[image: My result image]

How can I set the image and text as a sample image?

Comment: use `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 1):

same as sample :)  and FLATTENED

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                 android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/article_img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/item_img"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_above="@+id/lower_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_grey"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="#000"
            android:shadowDx="3"
            android:shadowDy="3"
            android:shadowRadius="6"
            android:text="Styling Android"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/lower_text"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_grey"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="A guide to applying styles and themes to Android apps"
            android:textColor="#CCC"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and the drawable bg_grey.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#a2515350"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: I'm sure the LinearLayout can be omitted.

Comment: @NoiseGenerator but you still need a parent to wrap the two textviews to have the transparent view size containing them right?

Comment: No. The transparency is on the TextView itself. Which is transparent in relation to the ImageView it hovers on. They are positioned in such a way they are one over the other.

Comment: @NoiseGenerator what about now is it better :)?

Comment: Muuuuuuuuuuuuuch better, indeed! Lovely!! +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/article_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/item_img" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <view
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:background="#7000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:shadowColor="#000"
                android:shadowDx="3"
                android:shadowDy="3"
                android:shadowRadius="6"
                android:text="Styling Android"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="A guide to applying styles and themes to Android apps"
                android:textColor="#CCC"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Too many nested layouts. Which is very bad for performances. FLATTEN your designs!